# How do I include a KB2544524 in an InstallShield project

Tags: localdb, installshield-2012

I have an application that uses SQLLocalDb that I am deploying via InstallShield Express Spring 2012.

LocalDb requires that the .Net update for KB2544514 be installed.  LocalDb is unable to connect to a LocalDb instance without this update.

When I add this exe to InstallShield as a custom action:

- An Error 1721 is encountered when NPD40-KB2544514-x86-x64.exe is executed unless the install is run as Administrator.
- If the setup that includes NPD40-KB2544514-x86-x64.exe is run as an Administrator, the installation succeeds.

Is there a way to daisy-chain the Microsoft KB update with the install that does not require a reight-click "Run as Administrator".  My concern is that instructions "Right click and Run as Administrator" will typically be overlooked by 99% of users and generate a high number of support calls.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a custom prerequisite via the "Install Shield Prerequisite editor" and associate it with your feature.